# C++: segfault when accessing data in unordered_map to set

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, set, unordered-map

I defined a simple structure EdgeList that is simply an `unordered_map` associating a string key with a `set` of strings.

```
class EdgeList{
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string,std::set<std::string>> map;

public:
  EdgeList(){};

  void insert(std::string key,std::string item);

  std::set<std::string> operator[](std::string key);
};

void EdgeList::insert(std::string key,std::string item)
{
  if(map.count(key)==0) //key not already in map
  {
    std::set<string> newset;
    map.emplace(key,newset);
  }
  map[key].insert(item);
}

std::set<string> EdgeList::operator[](string key){
  return map[key];
}
```

`EdgeList::insert` simply checks if the key already exists in the `unordered_map` (creating a new set if not) and inserts the item into the associated set. `EdgeList::operator[]` returns the set associated with the input key.

This is all simple enough, but something goes wrong when I try to access the data in an `EdgeList`. I keep getting mysterious segfaults when I try something like

```
EdgeList el;
//populate el
string KeyInEdgeList;

for(auto it=el[KeyInEdgeList].begin();it!=el[KeyInEdgeList].end();++it)
{
  std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

What might be going on? Is there a mistake in the class definition? Can I not use iterators for some reason? I'm at my wit's end, this shouldn't be complicated.

Comment: `std::map`'s `operator[]` [creates a key if it doesn't exist](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), so your `if` statement in `insert(string, string)` is redundant. For the same reason, in the `for` loop you are creating an empty set with `operator[]` and then try to dereference the iterator on the empty set inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator[]` returns a value:

```
std::set<std::string> operator[](std::string key);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is, a new `std::set` is copied from your underlying map every time you call this function, which will then get destroyed at the end of the expression. In other words:

```
for(auto it=el[KeyInEdgeList].begin();it!=el[KeyInEdgeList].end();++it)
//          |--- 1st set ---|             |--- 2nd set ---|
```

That's two *different* `set`s, both of which get destroyed by the time you actually dereference your iterator. Within the body of the `for` loop, you have a dangling reference.

What you want to do is have your `operator[]` return a reference and then, regardless, use a range-based for:

```
for (std::string const& elem : el[KeyInEdgeList]) { ... }
```